# Parsing a list of paths from file

Tags: python

I've written simple python script which provides me with a list of absolute paths of subfolders and subfolders of subfolders of given directory. The list is then written to file. My next goal would be to somehow parse that file in order to manipulate the permissions of directories (chmod, chgrp etc).

Here's a snippet of the file with some (MS Windows) paths, but actually I'll utilize it on Unix machine/s.

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\gopro\New folder\1
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\gopro\New folder\2
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\gopro\New folder\3
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\gopro\New folder\4
```

I'd appreciate any ideas on the best way to accomplish this. I'm a Python newb so keep that in mind.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Would it not work to just read each line into a list?

Comment: Consider using `pathlib` package for OS intercompatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned MS Windows, you can use `subprocess.run`, which basically runs commands in your shell.

```
import subprocess

with open("somefile.txt") as txtfile:
    for each_path in txtfile.readline():
        subprocess.run(
            ["chmod", "777", each_path],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            shell=True,
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted your answer. Should I use `subprocess` only when working between different OSes?

Comment: As @MrFuppes says "Consider using pathlib package for OS intercompatibility"

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but I think if you want to run shell commands on the directories, this is what you are looking for:

```py
import os # this is insecure, so USE WITH CAUTION (never in production). 

with open('list_of_directories.txt') as f:
    for folder_name in f.readlines(): # read each line from the file.
        os.system("chmod 777 {}".format(folder_name)) # os.system lets you run shell commands.
        # ...
```

Please note that while os.system() is the *easiest* way to solve the problem, it is extremely insecure. Never use it on a production script, but it's fine for quick utility scripts, as I presume that is your use case.

Comment: Thank you Kumar! That's like 99% of what I'm trying to accomplish with the difference that I was left under the impression that it's better to use `subprocess` instead of `os.system` for my shell commands. I'm really new to Python, so stupid questions are expected, I guess.

Comment: It is actually better to use `subprocess.call` than `os.system`, though in general both solutions aren't ideal for a production environment. For quick utility scripts I tend to use `os.system` because it's simpler to code/remember